# Oppening .QXD file on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, quark

I got an old qxp file created on a MAC with QuarkXPress.

Is there any way I could open and maybe edit this file on Ubuntu?

Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. Scribus is the Linux software more akin to QuarkXPress (DTP), and it [doesn't import propietary formats](http://wiki.scribus.net/index.php/Why_Scribus_doesn%27t_support_QuarkXpress_and_other_major_publishing_applications) (QuarkXPress , Pagemaker)

Answer (score 0):

There is a trial version of QuarkXPress for Windows and Mac.
I still haven't found a way to convert the file to another type, but I can at least edit and print it.

Not really a solution, but an alternitive